# Bootstrap 4 w/ASP.Net Nav Tabs/Pills click Opens Sub-menu and Page

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2008, bootstrap-4, nav

I am trying to create a Bootstrap based menu replacement for a very large VS2008 ASP.NET site that uses Master Pages.

The site has a two-level menu where the top row contains main areas, and second row contains content depending upon main menu area selected. After a day, I have a nice Bootstrap layout that looks and displays secondary menu content perfectly.

Using VS 2008 (cannot update due to existing codebase), 
nav and flex layout stuff with 
Bootstrap.bundle js/bootstrap css v4.1.3 and JQuery 3.3.1

Where I need help is getting the main menu Nav-Pills to both Open a url to a topic page (doesn't work) - and show the nav-content submenu div if exists (works).  I've cropped out a bunch of additional menus/content for the example below.

Clicking the Home Nav-Pill should show Default.aspx (already shown on load).
Home nav-Pill click screenshot:

[image]

Clicking the Nav-Search Pill should show the sub-menu AND load the Search.aspx page. Currently loads sub-menu(which will contain links to sub-area pages when done), but still shows the same page after click instead of search.aspx.
Search nav-Pill click screenshot:

[image]

Code I have so far:
MasterPage.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="CSS/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#eeeeee">
   <nav class="mainnav nav nav-pills bg-light  d-flex justify-content-md-between" role="tablist">  

        <a class=" d-flex nav-item" href="#">
            LOGO HERE<%-- <img height="44px" src="Images/logo_color.gif" alt="Logo" />--%>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav align-self-end">
            <li class="nav-item" style="height:25px">
                <%--<a class="nav-link active mr-2" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-blank" role="tab" aria-controls="blank" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>--%>
                <asp:HyperLink class="nav-link active mr-2" id="nav-home-tab" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nav-blank" role="tab" aria-controls="blank" aria-expanded="true"  runat="server">Home</asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <%--<a class="nav-link mr-2" id="nav-search-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nav-search" href="http://google.com" role="tab" aria-controls="search" aria-expanded="true">Search</a>    --%>
                <asp:HyperLink class="nav-link mr-2" id="nav-search-tab" data-toggle="tab" NavigateUrl="http://google.com" data-target="#nav-search" role="tab" aria-controls="search" aria-expanded="true"  runat="server">Search</asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
        </ul> 

        <div class=" d-flex d-inline-block align-content-end justify-content-end">
            <a href="#">Admin</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">Help</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">Logout</a>
        </div>        
    </nav>     

    <div class="tab-content col-sm-12" id="pills-tabContent">        
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-blank" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-search" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-search-tab" aria-expanded="false">
            <nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-sub-search" role="tablist">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link mr-2" href="#">Advanced Search</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link mr-2" href="#">Geographical Search</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">            
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Home page Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="cMainContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#dddddd">
     <br />
     Home Page Content    
</div>    
</asp:Content>
```

Search.aspx content:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>
<asp:Content ID="cSearchContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#dddddd">
    <br />
    Search Content 
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

I'd prefer an easy global way versus adding javascript events to every control. It almost seemed like I could use href/NavigateUrl for page name and data-target for submenu opening? - but doesn't work. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After days I finally got it partially working with javascript written onclick events to force page load considering data-toggle="tab" destroys use of URL to open sites... and more to load submenu...

Yet - finally gave up on approach as it was too much for little effect, and it didn't support sitmap submenu hierarchy. In the end I modified sites' web.sitemap adding custom values where needed, and modifying the sites' customtheme.Skin file to support Bootstrap values. End result was being able to continue using  for primary menu with autoloading of secondary submenu list. I had to add OnItemDatabound commands to mark tabs as selected (add or remove 'active' to CSS to show correct bootstrap images) when main or submenu item is selected (since main menu is not a bootstrap control).

I did find enough references to write a nice Repeater based submenu - posting here if it might help others (as most posts were single menus, this code shows how to add active/selected item support which I didn't find online):

```
<div class="subMenuContainer">
    <asp:Repeater ID="subMenu" OnItemDataBound="subMenu_OnItemDataBound" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        </HeaderTemplate>                                                                
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="nav-link mr-2 btn-sm btn-mycustombuttonstyle" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("description") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>                                                                
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>


protected void subMenu_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode;
        if (currentNode != null)
        {                
            HyperLink subMenuHyperlink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
            string curpage = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Substring(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            string linkTarget = subMenuHyperlink.NavigateUrl.Substring(subMenuHyperlink.NavigateUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            if (linkTarget.Equals(curpage)) {
                if (!subMenuHyperlink.CssClass.ToLower().Contains("active"))
                {
                    subMenuHyperlink.CssClass += " active";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (subMenuHyperlink.CssClass.ToLower().Contains("active"))
                {
                    subMenuHyperlink.CssClass = subMenuHyperlink.CssClass.Replace("active", "").Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```